# Debian source.list query

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

**TLDR**

1. Is it okay to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change the entry from `deb http://ftp.gb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free` to `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main`?
2. Would I ever need ftp link?
3. How many `source.list` files should I have in `/etc/apt`?

thanks for help / explanations  :)

**Background info**

When running updates I've been receiving this message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.gb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ftp.gb.debian.org'
```

I read [this](https://wiki.debian.org/ftp.debian.org) which suggested not using the ftp, but also says:

> If you're using it now, please switch to either the deb.debian.org CDN or a country-based DNS name such as ftp.us.debian.org, ftp.ca.debian.org, ftp.uk.debian.org, ...

Noticed I was wrongly using ftp.gb... (great britain?) so I changed to ftp.uk... but got this:

```
E: The repository 'http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian bullseye-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Therefore changed to:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
```

...and now updates fine. But just wanted to check this is okay in case my system for some reason needs the ftp link?

Also is it normal to have this many sources.list ?

```
puppydog@woofwoof:/etc/apt$ ls -l
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 18 09:17 apt.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 10  2021 auth.conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  150 Dec  6  2021 listchanges.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 28  2021 listchanges.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 10  2021 preferences.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1166 Feb 18 10:22 sources.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec  6  2021 sources.list~
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 18 09:15 sources.list.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1168 Feb 18 10:22 sources.list.save
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 18 10:20 trusted.gpg.d
```

I have `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64 5.10.0-21-amd64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No, I can't see why you would.
3. There's one `sources.list` file, that `apt` consults. In your directory there are also two backup files (`sources.list~` and `sources.list.save`), obviously ignored by `apt`. There's also a directory `sources.list.d/` which may contain files with the extension `.list`, that are also consulted by `apt`.

Comment: tyvm. that answers everything. much appreciated.

Comment: (sry - i don't have enough reputation to vote your answer as useful.)